# Solr commit taking too long

Tags: lucene, solr

My commit seems to be taking too much time, if you notice from the Dataimport 
status given below to commit 1000 docs its taking longer than 24 minutes

```
<str name="status">busy</str>
<str name="importResponse">A command is still running...</str>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:24:43.156</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1001</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">1658</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2011-06-07 09:15:17</str>
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 1000 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
</lst>
```

What can be causing this, I have tried looking for a reason or a way to improve 
this, but am just not able to find. At this rate my documents would never get 
indexed, given that I have more than 100,000 records coming into the database 
every hour.

Regards,
Rohit

Comment: Would need to see your data import handler configuration to get a better idea.

Comment: Have you looked at your database latency? Run the same query on your database and see how long it takes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you use solrj

```
public abstract class SolrServer
```

but if you do, you really need to index by chuncks/collections:

```
  public UpdateResponse add(Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs )
```

and not one by one

Answer (score 0):

Have added optimize=false in the data import handler. This has made things faster to some extent, now I am optimizing only during off peak hours.